# Formula referencing different spreadsheet needs to output both text and number formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a formula that references a different spreadsheet:

```
=IF('Raw Data Import'!G2=""," ",'Raw Data Import'!G2)
```

which outputs text format. However, since this cell is used in a different formula, it needs to output a number format. In other cells, I have used the *1 trick, but in this particular one I cannot, as occasionally `'Raw Data Import'!G2 will = "> 0.99"`, (in which case it is not used in the subsequent formula, and so needs to stay in text format) and occasionally it will equal an actual number, `"0.99"` for example.

*1 trick examples I tried are -

```
=IF(CELL("format",'Raw Data Import'!G2)=F2,'Raw Data Import'!G2*1,'Raw Data Import'!G2)
```

and

```
=IF(CELL("format",'Raw Data Import'!G2)=F2,TEXT('Raw Data Import'!G2,"0.##"),TEXT('Raw Data Import'!G2,"0.##"))
```

but, both seem to have no effect on the subsequent formula result.

Comment: @Raystafarian I have tried to format the cells, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Additionally since there are many lines of data I'd prefer the formula to handle the formatting on its own, although I don't know if it's possible. In regards to the *1 thing, I've tried `=IF(CELL("format",'Raw Data Import'!G2)=F2,'Raw Data Import'!G2*1,'Raw Data Import'!G2)` and on a different occassion trying to use the format result,
`=IF(CELL("format",'Raw Data Import'!G2)=F2,TEXT('Raw Data Import'!G2,"0.##"),TEXT('Raw Data Import'!G2,"0.##"))` both seem to have no effect on the subsequent formula result.

Comment: What is the format of the reference (`G2`) cell? What about if you try the `if` the other way? - `if(G2<>"",G2)`

Comment: All of the reference cells are in a general format, as it's just a raw data copy paste from a different spreadsheet. I now realize that using format as a qualifying statement won't work for that reason and I have to think of a different route.

Comment: I don't understand your rules, some example data would be useful. For instance what happens at 0? 1? .5? .25? .9? -1? etc

Comment: I posted the `if` statements that use this cell as a reference below in response to CallumDA33. Different things happen based on the value of the D column, but it needs to be >= 0.74, 0.89, 0.97 or 0.99. The problem is that the raw data also outputs "< 0.50" and "> 0.99", which mess up the less than or more than qualifiers, because of the returning of numbers formatted as text by these original statements in the question. So the raw data will always either be "< 0.50", a number between 0.51 and 0.99, or "> 0.99".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've entirely understood. Have you tried something like this?

```
=IFERROR(A1*1,A1)
```

Where **A1** contains "0.99" the number 0.99 will be returned, however, where **A1** contains "> 0.99" this will be returned in it's current state - as text

Comment: Ahhhh so close! Unfortunately there is also a possible reference cell value of < 0.50, which ultimately returns the same result as > 0.99. Right now I have the final qualifying statement, which I can post if needed, it's just very long nested IF statements and convoluted, recognizing "> 0.99" specifically. Off the top of my head I can't think of a way to exclude < 0.50, but I am very sleep deprived right now so hopefully it will make sense later.

Comment: It would be good to see more of what you've tried so that I can get a better idea of the exact problem. My advice for people that have long nested IF statements is usually to include a single VLOOKUP. Would this work in your situation?

Comment: I don't have a gigantic amount of experience with VLOOKUP, so I'm not absolutely sure. The long statement to follow is used to determine passing/passing with caution/failing if a number of cells meet certain specific criteria. `=IF(A2=" ","",IF(AND(0.54<=D2,D2<=1.46,C2<=1.75,OR(B2=0.99,B2="> 0.99")),"PASS",IF(AND(1.54<=D2,D2<=2.46,C2<=1.75,OR(B2>=0.97,B2="> 0.99")),"PASS",IF(AND(2.54<=D2,D2<=3.46,C2<=1.75,OR(B2>=0.89,B2="> 0.99")),"PASS",IF(AND(3.54<=D2,D2<=4.46,C2<=1.75,OR(B2>=0.74,B2="> 0.99")),"PASS",IF(K3="PASS WITH CAUTION","PASS WITH CAUTION","FAIL"))))))` in A2 is the original question

Comment: K3 is `=IF(AND(OR(B2=0.99,B2="> 0.99"),1.75<=C2,C2<=2.25,0.54<=D2,D2<=1.46),"PASS WITH CAUTION",IF(AND(OR(B2>=0.97,B2="> 0.99"),1.75<=C2,C2<=2.25,1.54<=D2,D2<=2.46),"PASS WITH CAUTION",IF(AND(OR(B2>=0.89,B2="> 0.99"),1.75<=C2,C2<=2.25,2.54<=D2,D2<=3.46),"PASS WITH CAUTION",IF(AND(OR(B2>=0.74,B2="> 0.99"),1.75<=C2,C2<=2.25,3.54<=D2,D2<=4.46),"PASS WITH CAUTION","FAIL"))))` B2 C2 and D2 are just numbers so I don't have to worry about them. Only A2 switches between number and text formats, and so the formula screws up when trying to determine if it's < or > a number.